# mongoose createConnection is not returning connection object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**index.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var cont = {};
async function connect()
{
    cont = await mongoose.createConnection("url",{ 
useNewUrlParser: true });
}
connect();
// console.log(cont);
const Cont = cont.model("contests",{name: String});
```

This gives the error cont.model is not a function. Also, console log gives the same output as the initial value `{}`. If I console log inside the function, then it does give some other output.

Intellisense says that `await has no affect on expression of these types`.

I would like to do `module.exports = {connect,cont}` For further use in my project.

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect solution which you can try

```
// Set up requirements
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Establish db connection
const DATABASE_URL = "Your DB URL"
mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL)
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', async () => console.log('Connected to Database'))

module.exports = db
```

Comment: but why is mine not working? It seems I am doing everything correct? Also, I want to establish connection to multiple databses, and then work with them. So they would be wrapped in the `connect()` function and then be exported. Atleast thats what my plan is.